# Excel VBA column B to single cell( coma separated ) , based on column A

Tags: vba, excel, range

data in excel:

```
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

Result I expected was:

```
1               Mary, John, Sam
2               Alaina, Edward
```

Answer (score 0):

User **allquixotic** answered a very similar question. Source [here](https://superuser.com/questions/561147/excel-concatenating-cells-where-reference-number-matches)

This is his VBA approach:

```
Option Explicit

Function allquixotic(param As Variant, search As Range, values As Range, Optional absolute As Boolean = False) As String

Dim sep As String, retval As String
Dim i As Integer, rownum As Integer
Dim look As Range, j As Range

sep = ", "
retval = ""
For i = 1 To search.Rows.Count
Set look = search.Cells(i, 1)
If absolute Then
        rownum = look.Row
Else
        rownum = i
End If

If look.Value = param Then
        If absolute Then
                Set j = values.Worksheet.Cells(rownum, values.Column)
        Else
                Set j = values.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
        retval = IIf(retval = "", retval & j.Value, retval & sep & j.Value)
End If

Next

allquixotic = retval

End Function

Use the worksheet function (feel free to rename it) by using a formula like

=allquixotic(A1,$A$1:$A$15,$B$1:$B$15,true)

Use the fill handle to put the formula in all the cells
```

The parameters are the following:

`=allquixotic(look_cell, key_range, value_range, absolute)`

`look_cell:` The first parameter, should be a **single cell** or a **value literal**. Valid input includes things like 3, $6.25, "Hello", etc. This is the value that you are trying to find in key_range.

`key_range:` This should be a **range** of cells (more than one cell); if `absolute` is true then you will get very strange results unless this is a **contiguous** range (all the values are in sequential rows).

`value_range:` This should be a **range** of cells (more than one cell); if `absolute` is true then you will get very strange results unless this is a **contiguous** range (all the values are in sequential rows).

`absolute:` If true, then we will use the **absolute row number** (relative to the number of rows in the entire spreadsheet) of each "found" row in the `key_range` to determine what row to extract a value from `value_range` on. If false, we will use relative numbers; for instance, if we find a match in the **third** row of `key_range`, then we will extract the value from the **third** row of `value_range`. Recommended value is FALSE, or you can omit it to default to that.

**Note**: This function does not support the case where the key and value ranges are in **columns**, but it should be fairly easy to adapt it to that.

Also, if you specify multiple columns in either the `key_range` or the `value_range`, only the leftmost column will be used.

> Again, all credit goes to **allquixotic**.